# Android: Accept an ObjectInputStream and pass it on WITHOUT reading

Tags: android, sockets, serialization

I'm sending an Object via a Socket by using getObjectOutputStream.

However, at the server's end (that recieves the object), I wish to accept it as it is and just pass it on to another application.

At the server's end, if I use getObjectInputStream, it throws a ClassNotFound exception because there is no class of the object there. So, how do I simply recieve the object -- or its bytestream -- and just pass it as is, to another app ?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the bytes, using the classic copy loop on the socket input and output streams:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Don't use Object streams at all as the man in the middle.

Comment: Hi EJP. Will your solution enable me to recieve the intact object finally, using getObjectInputStream ? I just ask because the writing is being done in a loop and not in "one go".

Comment: Of course, that's why I suggested it when I answered your question. I don't understand the part about 'writing being done in a loop' but as long as you transfer all the bytes correctly you can't possibly have a problem.

Comment: OK. While sending from the Client too do I have to use your code, or can I just send it via ObjectOutputStream ? (I thought the writing in a loop may send data in burts, which may be processed differently instead of in one attempt).

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to send objects you have to use ObjectOutputStream at the initial sender, but only you know whether you really need to send objects. I don't understand your theory about bursts either.

Comment: Actually I'm 1) Sending an Object via a socket to a server, 2) Server recieves it, and then 3) Sends it to another app within the same virtual machine. So, according to your suggestion I'll pass the object using ObjectInputStream itself, and then from the server to the app I'll use your code. Forget about the bursts etc.

Comment: OK. I finally did this by making the client send the object using the ObjectOutputStream and recieve it at the server using ObjectInputStream. At the server I no longer send it to the other app, and just execute it at the receipt point.